# Distinct records based on a field string compare, average a field and return dynamic objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using MVC 5 where I have the following Model / table called Question;

[image]

I want to produce the following result;

[image]

My objective is to obtain a list of records reflecting DISTINCT Topics with an average of all the scores for the given Distinct Topic.

```
var result = from q in db.Questions
               where q.Topic.Distinct()
              select new Question
              {
                  Category = q.Category,                             
                  Topic = q.Topic,                              
                  Store1Rating = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Topic == q.Topic).Average(s1 => s1.Store1Rating).ToString(),
                  Store2Rating = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Topic == q.Topic).Average(s2 => s2.Store2Rating).ToString()
              };
```

I know I'm way off on the LINQ statement but I only have about 6 weeks of doing basic LINQ statements under my belt.  This is a whole other layer of complexity over basic LINQ for me.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `GroupBy`

```
var result = db.Questions.GroupBy(x => new
//grouping data by category and topic, rows which have same category and topic will be in a group
{
    x.Category,
    x.Topic
}).Select(g => new
//now selecting category and topic for each group and the data we want
{
    g.Key.Category,
    g.Key.Topic,
    //calculate Store1Rating average of all rows which has same category and topic as this group
    Store1Rating = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Category == g.Key.Category && x.Topic == g.Key.Topic).Average(x => x.Store1Rating),
    //calculate Store2Rating average of all rows which has same category and topic as this group
    Store2Rating = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Category == g.Key.Category && x.Topic == g.Key.Topic).Average(x => x.Store2Rating),
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  Now can you explain whats going on ;)  Any suggestions on how to learn LINQ > basics.

Comment: I added some comments. you can start learning from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: I'm getting the following error;     The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`7[Question.Models.Category,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.Double,System.Double]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Question.Models.Questions]'.

Comment: It is because type of items in `result` are anonymous but you are trying to add them to a dictionary of another type.

Comment: Ok.  I'm using MVC, the logic above is in my controller where I'm working with a Model called Question.   I want to retrieve the records from the db and hand off the model to the view.

Comment: that's a whole new question, ask it. @user3022845

Comment: No, you should ask your new problem in another question.

Comment: Hopefully this is more clear; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082534/how-to-write-a-dynamic-linq-statement-using-a-strongly-typed-model-in-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Try code below.  Use following webpage for reference : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable Questions = new DataTable();

            Questions.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            Questions.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            Questions.Columns.Add("Topic", typeof(string));
            Questions.Columns.Add("Store1Rating", typeof(int));
            Questions.Columns.Add("Store2Rating", typeof(int));

            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,"Food","Pizza", 5, 6 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Food", "Pizza", 4, 5 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Food", "Ice Cream", 4, 5 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Beverage", "Beer", 3, 4 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Beverage", "Soda", 4, 5 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Food", "Pizza", 5, 6 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Food", "Pizza", 4, 5 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "Food", "Ice Cream", 3, 4 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "Beverage", "Beer", 4, 5 });
            Questions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, "Beverage", "Soda", 5, 6 });

            var summary = Questions.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Topic"))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Id"),
                    category = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Category"),
                    topic = x.Key,
                    rating1 = x.Select(y => y.Field<int>("Store1Rating")).ToList().Average(),
                    rating2 = x.Select(y => y.Field<int>("Store2Rating")).ToList().Average()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```