# How to write a DISTINCT or GROUPBY LINQ statement using a strongly typed model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Model called Survey as highlighted below;

[image]

I want to write a LINQ statement in my controller that will query the Survey Table and return distinct records by 'Topic'.  Each distinct record will have an average rating.  For example;

[image]

I'm new to LINQ and have a hard time when creating anything that is not basic.

My attempt;

```
var results = from s in db.Surveys
                      where s.Topic.Distinct()
                      select new Survey
                      {
                          SurveyId = s.SurveyId,
                          Category = s.Category.Name,
                          Topic = s.Topic,
                          Store1Rating= db.Surveys.Average(s => s.Score1).Value,
                          Store2Rating= db.Surveys.Average(s => s.Score2).Value
                      };
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: nothing, my mistake.  thanks for providing criticism and not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var survey1 = new Survey() { Topic = "topic1", Store1Rate = 5, Store2Rate = 4 };
        var survey2 = new Survey { Topic = "topic2", Store1Rate = 6, Store2Rate = 2 };
        var survey3 = new Survey { Topic = "topic2", Store1Rate = 7, Store2Rate = 2 };
        var survey4 = new Survey { Topic = "topic3", Store1Rate = 6, Store2Rate = 4 };
        var survey5 = new Survey { Topic = "topic3", Store1Rate = 1, Store2Rate = 2 };
        var survey6 = new Survey { Topic = "topic3", Store1Rate = 2, Store2Rate = 9 };

        List<Survey> surveys = new List<Survey>() { survey1, survey2, survey3, survey4, survey5, survey6 };

        var result = surveys.GroupBy(s => s.Topic).Select(s => new { Topic = s.Key, Rate1 = s.Average(a => a.Store1Rate), Rate2 = s.Average(a => a.Store2Rate) });
    }
}

class Survey
{
    public string Topic;
    public int Store1Rate;
    public int Store2Rate;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, it didn't work however because  its Anonymous.  "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`3[System.String,System.Double,System.Double]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LMSSurvey.Models.Survey]'."

Comment: Dissappointed answer is correct, however if you want to pass that to a view you have to add to list ...    'var result = surveys.GroupBy(s => s.Topic).Select(s => new { Topic = s.Key, Rate1 = s.Average(a => a.Store1Rate), Rate2 = s.Average(a => a.Store2Rate) });'

Answer (score 0):

Dissapointed is correct
If you want to use this as a model you have to cast it to a list for example:

```
`var result = surveys.GroupBy(s => s.Topic).Select(s => new { Topic = s.Key, Rate1 = s.Average(a => a.Store1Rate), Rate2 = s.Average(a => a.Store2Rate) }).ToList();`
```

Then in your controller you do a:

```
`return View("ViewName", result)`
```